# Multiple terminals, multiple commands, lxterminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, tabs, raspberry-pi

I am working with Python. Writing a script, I am attempting to use `os.system()` to open a new terminal, create new tabs and run different commands in each respective tab (which appear to run simultaneously).

I am familiar with `gnome-terminal` as it is what I have used in the past, however the system I am working with at the moment, a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian), uses `lxterminal`.

I have always used

```
    os.system("gnome-terminal --tab -e 'command1' --tab -e 'command2' ")
```

with success, but I don't know how to reproduce these results with `lxterminal`. So, basically I'm asking if and how `lxterminal` can do this.

I can create the tabs, no problem, with

```
    lxterminal --tabs=1,2,3
```

and

```
    lxterminal --tabs=1,2,3 --command="command1"
```

does create the tabs and execute the first command in the first tab... but that's as close as I can get, and obviously that doesn't do the trick of multiple commands in tabs 2 and 3.

If the `lxterminal` man gives any clues I'm just missing them... I thought maybe the brackets under `-t`, `--title`, and `--tabs` section might point to details for those, so I tried something like

```
    lxterminal --tabs=1[--command="command1"],2[--command="command2"]
```

But that only titled the tabs.... as expected.

All of my searches point me back to `gnome-terminal` but if there's a way to make `lxterminal` do this, I'd love to know.

Comment: Is running the commands in `screen` session an option?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Try run the command like this:

```
lxterminal --command 'command1 & command2'
```

Anyway there are old bug reports regarding the [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxterminal/+bug/1050576)

Comment: OP wants to run two commands simultaneously in separate tabs, not sequentially in one tab.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is so late and I'm not an expert just sharing, but I hope anyone who has a similar problem can be helped.

to do that you need to make a new bash file **example.bash**
then insert command you want, like;

```
#!/bin/bash

lxterminal --command 'cd /Apath/Bpath/Cpath/ &&  sudo example.bash/py/sh/bash'
lxterminal --command 'cd /Dpath/Epath/Fpath/ &&  sudo example.bash/py/sh/bash'
lxterminal --command 'cd /Gpath/Hpath/Ipath/ &&  sudo example.bash/py/sh/bash'
```

it will open 3 of the script in the new terminal ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ